# converting case on selected alphabet in R using gsub

Tags: regex, r

I have a string that I need to convert it into pre-specified case format:

`CHAN TAI MAN` needs to be converted to `CHAN Tai Man`

The string is actually a chinese name. I know how to capture the `AI` and `AN` in my case using the following `regex` command in R:

`^[A-Z]+ [A-Z]([A-Z]+) [A-Z]([A-Z]+)` can pick up the `AI` and `AN` for me, but I don't know how to use `regex` to conver them to lower case.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `sub`:

```
s <- "CHAN TAI MAN"

sub("(\\w+ \\w)(\\w+)( \\w)(\\w+)", "\\1\\L\\2\\U\\3\\L\\4", s, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "CHAN Tai Man"
```

Here, `\\L` means lowercase, and `\\U` means uppercase.